ALB Target unhealthy check request timed out
I noticed that the Application Load Balancer is marking instances as unhealthy. The reason for the error is "request timed out." How can I resolve this?



Couple of things to check is whether the security groups are good (i.e Egress rules in ALB's SG and Ingress rules in Target's SG). Also it is worth to check whether the target web application is listening on port 80. Do a curl test from another EC2 instance in the same VPC which is also allowed in the Security group

Doesn't Elastic beanstalk handle these things automatically when you recompile it?
